# How to build the above model

Tags: alloy

I am a beginner in Alloy.
I'm trying to model a math problem.
I want to prove the theorem that the plane exists at least four lines, I use the below four axioms to prove the theorems.

- axiom 1: There exists at least one line;
- axiom 2: Every line contain
  at least three points;
- axioms3: Not all points lie on the same line;
- axioms4: There is exactly one line through any two points.

Theorem : There exist at least four lines.
How to build the above model?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried so far. You can [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Please refrain from editing questions that have already been answered. If you have a new question, just create a new post so as to keep Q&A consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general approach to modeling such a problem in Alloy.

- First identify the relevant concepts (e.g. Point,Line ...) and declare them as so called signatures.
- Then declare in the body of those signatures so called fields defining relations between those concepts. (e.g. containment relation between a line and points).
- Once such structure is defined you can express your axioms as invariants in so called facts.

To learn how to declare signatures, fields and facts, please have a look at the Alloy online tutorial: http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/